# Footer link overflow

Tags: css, overflow, hyperlink

I have an image in my footer linked to my blog. This link is overflowing to the copyright and I have no idea why.

I never added a link to the copyright itself only to the image but for some reason when I hover over the copyright it links to the blog. I can't explain it this has never happened to me before.

Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
  <footer>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="left">
                    <img src="#" alt="">
                <h6>Title</h6>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="middle">
                <p><a href="#"><img src="#" alt=""></p>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <p><a href="#"><img src="#" alt=""></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

CSS

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #212119;
}

.footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #474741;
}

.footer .left {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: left;
}

.footer .left img {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
    height: 110px;
    width: 113px;
}

.footer .left h6 {
    color: #474741;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.footer .left p {
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.footer .left p:last-child {
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.footer .middle {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

.footer .middle p {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.footer .right {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    width: 33%;
}

.footer .right p {
    margin-top: -152px;
}

.copyright {
    clear: both;
}

.copyright p{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
    color: #e8ad4f;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your `a` tags...

```
<p><a href="#"><img src="#" alt=""></p>
```

... becomes ...

```
<p><a href="#"><img src="#" alt=""></a></p>
```

Otherwise everything that follows will be enclosed in the link.

Comment: oh wow that's a lil embarrassing. Glad it was something simple though. Thanks.